# rails serverの立ち上げのエラーについて: cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

プログラミングを独学でgoogleなどで調べて学習しています。

以下の手順でコマンドを実行すると、エラーが表示されてしまいます。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
rails new sample
cd sample
rails s
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.3.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
/Users/hiratashinichi/puma-test/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)
```

いくつか対処を自分で調べて実行しましたがお手上げ状態です。
私自身が対処したことは

- gem fileのlistenのバージョン変更
- rbenvとrubyのバージョンを変更して再度rails new アプリ名を実行
- webpackerのインストールが成功してないのでrails webpacker:installを試すも同じように--listenエラーが起こります。(yarn nodeもinstall済みです）

どなたか私と同じ状況になった事のある方はどのように対処しましたでしょうか？
初学者なので質問文に関してはご理解お願い申し上げます。

### 追記

Masafumi Okuraさんコメントありがとうございます。`cd sample`をした後`bundle install`もやってみたのですがやはりload errorでした。gemfileの内容はこの通りですがなにか不備があるんですかね

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

私自身も調べながらコメントアウトして書き換えたりバージョンの方もいじったりしてみたのですがrails abord!などのerrorに繋がってしまいます。

Comment: `bundle install`コマンドは実行しましたか？もし実行していなければそれが原因の可能性があります。実行済みでしたら、`Gemfile`の内容を追記していただけるとよいかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

以下のファイルを削除してみてください。
-app/tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache
-app/tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache

Comment: コメント有難うございます。file自体rmしてもbundle installで元に戻ってしまいます。改めてrubyを2.6.3に変えて今度はrails tutolialに沿ってgemfileを置き換えたりしてみたりしましたがfile内のgemの互換性があってないなど新しいエラーにぶつかるばかりで結局load errorの原因が分かりません。

Comment: GitHubのIssueで、bootsnapのcache関係のバグの報告がありましたので、それに関係するものと思い回答致しました。
私には、他に思い当たる解決策は無いです。申し訳ないです、失礼致します。